# More Elegant way to Batch Validate Phone Numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got this test database that I want to use for validating a phone numbers.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/18a38/3

However it currently only works with a single number at a time.

```
SELECT
    countries.locl_ctry_id,
    countries.icc,
    countries.active,

    networks.locl_ntwrk_id,
    networks.locl_ctry_id,

    numberings.locl_ntwrk_id,
    numberings.ndc

FROM countries

LEFT JOIN networks
    ON networks.locl_ctry_id = countries.locl_ctry_id

LEFT JOIN numberings
    ON numberings.locl_ntwrk_id = networks.locl_ntwrk_id

WHERE
    countries.active = 'true'
AND numberings.locl_ntwrk_id NOTNULL
AND CONCAT(countries.icc, numberings.ndc) LIKE LEFT('381645554330‬', CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(countries.icc, numberings.ndc)))
```

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to streamline this and have it process multiple numbers at a time instead of just one?

Comment: Is there an actual question here relating to phone numbers?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Example is at sqlFiddle.

Comment: Is the `LIKE` expression the "check" on phone numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your query to use derived table:

```
WITH numbers(num) AS 
(
  VALUES ('381645554330‬'), ('1223456')  -- here goes argument list
), cte AS (
SELECT
    countries.locl_ctry_id,
    countries.icc,
    countries.active,
    networks.locl_ntwrk_id,
    networks.locl_ctry_id,
    numberings.locl_ntwrk_id,
    numberings.ndc
FROM countries
LEFT JOIN networks
    ON networks.locl_ctry_id = countries.locl_ctry_id
LEFT JOIN numberings
    ON numberings.locl_ntwrk_id = networks.locl_ntwrk_id
WHERE countries.active = 'true'
  AND numberings.locl_ntwrk_id  IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM  numbers
LEFT JOIN cte
  ON CONCAT(icc, ndc) LIKE LEFT(numbers.num, CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(icc,ndc)))
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(numbers.num)=9  -- additional conditions
;
```

**[sqlfiddle.com demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/18a38/11/0)**

Comment: This works well. And here if I wanted to add another condition the number is supposed to meet like `CHAR_LENGTH(numbers.num)=9` where do I add it?

Comment: `CHAR_LENGTH(numbers.num)=numberings.size`

Comment: @Borsn Simply by using `WHERE` or `LEFT ... ON ... AND ...` depeneds on needs

Comment: Right. But `9` is a number thats obtained from table `numberings.size`. If I use `numbers.num` in the first `Select` it can't see it. If I use `numberings.size` in the second `Select` it can't see it also.

Comment: @Borsn . . . You should ask another question.  Lukasz seems to have answered the one you asked here.